# Can this be done in classic ASP?

Tags: input, asp-classic

I am just wondering if I can make an input field that does something similar to the image in classic asp?

a textbox or whatever that will use the up and down arrows to increase/decrease the value in the field

I don't know .net other than some basic visual basic.net and even there I don't remember seeing a windows form control that will do that other than say a textbox and a VScrollBar next to it.

If it can't be done then no biggy, just curious

[image example mockup http://www.sshcs.com/xbmc/img/mockup.png](http://www.sshcs.com/xbmc/img/mockup.png)

Comment: You can do this with HTML5 `<input type="number">` element, so it's possible in classic asp, but you have to consider the client side.

Answer (score 3):

As I see it it doesnt have much to do with classic asp, its client side.

look into jquery ui for those fancy controls.

[www.jqueryui.com](http://www.jqueryui.com)

If you wanna buy neat looking ones try Kendo UI:

http://demos.kendoui.com/themebuilder/web.html